# Replace function not working in C#, but working in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, replace

Replace function working when using command

```
exec MyStoredProcedure param1, param2,
```

etc..., but when running it through C# code, it is not replacing the text properly, so I end up with an email that still says @@Comments, instead of the actual comments. I try to check it in SQL Server 2008, but it works fine and the email comes through properly. Is there something that I need to check?

Here is my C# code:

```
public static void SetRequestStatusChange(int reqID, int newStatus, string assignTo)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spUpdateRequest", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // Status
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RequestNo", SqlDbType.Int, 4));
    cmd.Parameters["@RequestNo"].Value = 276;

    // Queue
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 12));
    cmd.Parameters["@userID"].Value = "1091912";

    // State
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RequestStatus", SqlDbType.Int, 4));
    cmd.Parameters["@RequestStatus"].Value = 2;

    // Buyer Emp ID
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@assignedTo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 12));
    cmd.Parameters["@assignedTo"].Value = "1091912";

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException err)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Data Error." + err.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        //close the connection 
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is the part of the stored procedure that actually performs the replace. The actual stored procedure is very long, and calls many other stored procedures (I didn't write it), and it would be extremely cumbersome to read.

```
select @html = replace(replace(replace(@html, '@@COMMENTS', case when @activityID <> 20 then  'The following comments were noted when the Request' else '' end +

   case @ActivityID when  2 then ' was submitted: ' +  case when requestorComments > '' then requestorComments  else 'None' end
   when 0 then '' 
   when  4 then ' was edited: ' + isnull(L.Comments,  'None') 
   when  15 then ' was edited: ' + isnull(LL.Comments,  'None') 
   when  20 then ''
   when  21 then  ' material was returned: ' + case when dbo.fnLastComment(lamSpecRecallComments) > '' then replace(dbo.fnLastComment(lamSpecRecallComments),':',':  ') else 'None' end
   when  -21 then  ' material was returned: ' + case when dbo.fnLastComment(lamSpecRecallComments) > '' then replace(dbo.fnLastComment(lamSpecRecallComments),':',':  ') else 'None' end
   when  8 then ' was approved: ' + case when ccMgrCOmments > '' then ccMgrCOmments  else 'None' end
   when  9 then ' was approved: ' + case when lamAprCOmments > '' then lamAprCOmments  else 'None' end
   when 13 then ' was stored: ' + case when dbo.fnLastComment(lamSpecCOmments) > '' then dbo.fnLastComment(lamSpecCOmments)  else 'None' end
   when -8 then ' was closed: ' + case when ccMgrCOmments > '' then ccMgrCOmments  else 'None' end
   when -9 then ' was closed: ' + case when lamAprCOmments > '' then lamAprCOmments  else 'None' end
   else '' end), 

   '@@PLEASE',
   case when @activityID =  8 or @activityID = 9 or @activityID = 20 or @activityID = 2  then 'Please click the link below to view the Request and ensure it is worked expeditiously.'
   else '' end),'@@RECALL',@list)  

   from (select * from strgRequests where requestNumber = @requestID) r
   left join (select * from  ActivityLog  where TransactionID = @transactionID) L on 1 = 1
   left join (select * from  ActivityLineItemLog where TransactionID = @transactionID) LL on 1 = 1
```

@@Comments, @@RECALL, and @@Please come from a table. This allows for the emails to be customized.

Comment: What do you mean it "*still* says @@Comments"?  Where is that defined?  Perhaps you should show us your SP?

Comment: Print out the arguments passed into the stored procedure (or store them in a table).  Most likely, the code you posted is not getting executed, so the error is probably earlier.  This code replaces '@@COMMENT' with something, but that is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

"@@" is normally used for global/default variables.
"@" is normally used for parameters.

I'd have to see more code to be sure.  My instincts tell me that switching your @@ for @ is the next direction you should take in sorting this out.

Also, if a field has the value of "@@Comments" you probably have a code somewhere that looks like:

set @cmd=`insert into Table (field,field,field) values ('somethinguseful','@@Comments','more stuff')

exec(@cmd)

This has two problems.

1. You didn't translate @@Comments
2. You are injection prone.

use something like:

execute sp_executesql N'insert into Table (field,field,field) values (@var1,@var2,@var3)'
,N'@var1 varchar(256)'
, @var1=@Comments
...

Comment: But why does it work correctly if I do exec spUpdateRequest 276, '1091912', 2, '1091912' directly in the database?